# Need help in finding element value in Puppeteer using , await page.waitForSelector() or await page.waitForXPath()

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbV6Q.png)[

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.DateRangeSelectorstyles__DateInput-sc-5md5uc-2.kXffji.sc-cSHVUG.VGFsW'); 

await page.type('.DateRangeSelectorstyles__DateInput-sc-5md5uc-2.kXffji.sc-cSHVUG.VGFsW','01-01-2020');
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKsHE.png)Need help in finding element value in Puppeteer using , await page.waitForSelector() or await page.waitForXPath()

```
<input placeholder="" readonly="" class="DateRangeSelectorstyles__DateInput-sc-5md5uc-2 kXffji sc-cSHVUG VGFsW" autocomplete="off" value="01-Nov-2020">
```

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIltp.png)

Comment: no, but you have not shown how you have tried to solve your problem yourself, so people are not very keen on solving it instead of you. A similar question has also been asked multiple times, you'd be able to find an answer faster yourself.

Comment: after ctrl+shift+i  I used copy> css selector  & copy xpath

Comment: await page.waitForSelector('#root > div > div > div.PastOrdersWrappersstyles__FiltersAndOrderList-sc-79pfk8-0.imAXGj > div.DateRangeSelectorstyles__DateInputWrapper-sc-5md5uc-0.hgwIyL > div.DateRangeSelectorstyles__DateSelectComponent-sc-5md5uc-6.dvlBQH > input') 


await page.type('#root > div > div > div.PastOrdersWrappersstyles__FiltersAndOrderList-sc-79pfk8-0.imAXGj > div.DateRangeSelectorstyles__DateInputWrapper-sc-5md5uc-0.hgwIyL > div.DateRangeSelectorstyles__DateSelectComponent-sc-5md5uc-6.dvlBQH > input','23-11-2020')
 new toPuppeteer tried with xpath Thanks so much
@pavelsaman

Answer (score 0):

With [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options), you use [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), for example like this:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.DateRangeSelectorstyles__DateInput-sc-5md5uc-2.kXffji.sc-cSHVUG.VGFsW');
```

or like this:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('input[value="01-Nov-2020"]');
```

Comment: What does it mean? I don't sit next to you, I have no idea what you see.

Comment: somehow this aint working await page.waitForSelector('.DateRangeSelectorstyles__DateInput-sc-5md5uc-2.kXffji.sc-cSHVUG.VGFsW');


and cant use this approach

Comment: Can you please point me in some direction? ,after ctrl+shift+i I used copy> css selector & copy xpath

Comment: "It isn't working" can mean several things, I have no idea which one.

Comment: With this command <--
    await page.waitForSelector('.DateRangeSelectorstyles__DateInput-sc-5md5uc-2.kXffji.sc-cSHVUG.VGFsW');

    await page.type('.DateRangeSelectorstyles__DateInput-sc-5md5uc-2.kXffji.sc-cSHVUG.VGFsW', '01-01-2000');-->

Getting the following error
(node:11532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: waiting for selector `.DateRangeSelectorstyles__DateInput-sc-5md5uc-2.kXffji.sc-cSHVUG.VGFsW` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

Comment: It does what it says, it didn't find any element with this selector, so it timed out. You need to find out what's going on on the site. The selector is correct, but that might not be the only reason for timeout.